# Excel not recognizing values as equal

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table of values that I am trying to pull a number from by using a for loop that chooses the right table column based a value that was input into my spreadsheet. The input value (FvX2) is rounded to the nearest tenths place using the Ceiling function. This is then compared to values in the table by increasing the column number until the rounded value in the table equals the rounded number input into the spreadsheet. My problem is excel will not recognize when the two values are equal and never returns a value for Fvcl. I think this has something to do with the ceiling function but don't know how to get around it. Any ideas? Input value is 0.52 and is rounded to 0.6. Table values start at 0.1 and increase to 0.6 by increments of 0.1. Excel will not return Fvcl when FvX2 equals table value.

```
Dim FvX1 As Double
Dim FvX2 As Double
Dim Fvcl As Double

FvX2 = WorksheetFunction.Ceiling(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B7").Value, 0.1)
FvX1 = FvX2 - 0.1

For j = 0 To 5
   
    If Worksheets("Tables").Cells(11, 2 + j).Value = FvX2 Then
        Fvcl = 2 + j 
    End If
Next j
```

Comment: Sounds like [floating-point error](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2008/04/10/understanding-floating-point-precision-aka-why-does-excel-give-me-seemingly-wrong-answers/). More reading [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/floating-point-arithmetic-inaccurate-result).

Comment: Output the two values you want to compare with `debug.print` or `msgbox`. Also check if they are the same variable type using [VarType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/vartype-function). If the problem is floating-point error as mentioned by @BigBen then see if there is consistently a small difference between the numbers and maybe you could do something like `if num1 - num2 < 0.0100`?

Comment: @BigBen That worked! Thank you for the information!

Comment: @ garbb thanks for the response. I was able to handle this using the round function per the information BigBen provided.